# React Native multiple modals on one page question

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog

I have got 6 different buttons on one page that each need to open a modal window. Now I don't want to write out 6 different modals. So when the user presses the first button it will pull up a modal with the reported info on the "shopping info", whereas on the second button it would bring up the info on "graphical info".

```
const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.expensesList} onPress={() => {setModalVisible(true)}}>
      <FontAwesome5 name="shopping-cart" size={40} color="black" style={styles.iconStyle} />
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.expensesList} onPress={}> {/* Different modal? */}
      <Foundation name="graph-bar" size={40} color="black" />
    </TouchableOpacity>

<Modal
    animationType="slide"
    transparent={true}
    visible={modalVisible}
    style={{ margin: 0 }}
    onRequestClose={() => {}}>

// Different info based on which button was pressed

</Modal>
```

These are for reporting purposes so each one will have the same styling and close button. But I want to be able to only have one modal that opens different ones dependent on which button was pressed. Is this doable?

If I am not clear enough please let me know. I am new to React Native.

**EDIT** - I am NOT trying to open multiple modals at once. Only one will be open at a time. But I want to be able to change the info in the ONE modal, dependent on which button was clicked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can add a state that will take care of the action triggered and then based on this state you can change the content of the modal, see an example and let me know if it's well suited for your case:

```js
const [actionTriggered, setActionTriggered] = useState(''); // here we go

const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

   <>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.expensesList} onPress={() => {
        setModalVisible(true);
        setActionTriggered('ACTION_1'); // HERE
      }}>
        <FontAwesome5 name="shopping-cart" size={40} color="black" style={styles.iconStyle} />
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.expensesList} onPress={() => {
        setActionTriggered('ACTION_2'); // HERE
      }}> {/* Different modal? */}
        <Foundation name="graph-bar" size={40} color="black" />
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        style={{ margin: 0 }}
        onRequestClose={() => { }}>

        {/* inside the modal view, depending on the action type do something */}
        {actionTriggered === 'ACTION_1' ?
          <View>
            {/* .... something you want to show in case of the first modal opened  */}
          </View> :
          actionTriggered === 'ACTION_2' ?
            <View>
              {/* // .... something you want to show in case of the second modal opened  */}
            </View> :
            null}
      </Modal>
   </>
```

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you so much for the help on this! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You can mark as answered by clicking on check icon beside my answer ;)

Comment: @Mostav hi, amazing answer. Thank you but i have a problem it works on IOS but not android. why is that?

Comment: I dont't think it has a relation with this solution maybe you have a specific version that causes the issue, i think you should post your code to be able to help